# Clear log files from database and cache/temp files from magento root

Tags: magento-1.9, database, cache, log, setup

I want to deploy a magento site. But firstly I need to clear temp/cache files from magento directory as well as database.

I don't know how to do both by a single script.

> Note :- Need to remove only temp files from directory and database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to look at my gist here, it contains code for clearing the log, cache and temp in both files and database.

Download it from:

https://gist.github.com/VIVEKLUCKY1848/19d4b2853dad7e802b33c24199ab65f4

**Hope this works for you**

Comment: There is no file on your link.